# How to implement Signal transmitted by RF source

Tags: matlab, digital-communications

I am implementing a research paper, in which i have to implement signal transmitted by RF source in matlab. The equation given in this paper is : $s(n)e^{j \cdot 2 \cdot \pi \cdot f \cdot n}$. Any help in this regard would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume this would be as follows:

```
s*exp(j*2*pi*f*n)
```

Where:

n: sample index 
s: baseband signal, magnitude and phase for each sample 
f: carrier frequency in cycles/sample

Note how the carrier as a discrete signal is given in cycles per sample. This is the normalized frequency and is related to the desired frequency $F$ in Hz by dividing by the sampling rate $f_s$ as follows:

$f = F/f_s$

Comment: Yes...but how to implement it. Can you please share small code

Comment: @charu the grey box is the code. Is it the math you don't understand or how to code in MATLAB?

Comment: I am good in writing MATLAB codes. But in this grey box, what values should I consider for s, f, n. If you can tell these values then I can easily code. Also I want to know math behind taking these values.

Comment: @charu- i arleady wrote in detail what each unit is right below the gray box. I don't know what your specific baseband signal is or carrier but it is as simple as that once you have those signals in MATLAB.

Comment: sir, my signal is ambient RF signal. We can consider the signal to be a wi-fi or signal from TV transmitter etc. I understood all the things except 's'. Can you please mention what exactly i should take for baseband signal 's'.

Comment: That would be the magnitude and phase that you want your carrier frequency to be at each sample. This is your waveform that is changing in amplitude and phase versus time and the rest of the equation is what moves that waveform to the RF frequency.

Comment: You could generate a random sequence of real and imaginary samples and then low pass filter that to your defined bandwidth and that would be representative of most RF signals.

Comment: Thanks a lot sir....